# Проблема с модальными окнами bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap

У меня такой вопрос:
При загрузке страницы через консоль увидел такую ошибку:

> ReferenceError: Popper is not defined

У меня скачаны полноценные bootstrap.css и bootstrap.js.
Как я знаю что popper.js уже входит в них. Несколько дней назад модальные окна работали (появлялись по нажатию на соответствующую кнопку с прописанными атрибутами и айди).

Ломаю голову уже третий день - результата ноль. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно причина в том, что вы используете библиотеки с беты, либо обновились до релиза частично. Вы вообще пробовали гуглить по запросу `ReferenceError: Popper is not defined`?

Comment: Да, вы правы, у меня beta2. А как тогда это возможно исправить?
Заменить файлы на релизные? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Да, гуглил первым делом, иначе не написал бы на стак

Comment: Я нашел похожую проблему [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952775/bootstrap-4-uncaught-referenceerror-popper-is-not-defined). Думаю вам придется обновиться до релиза. На сколько я знаю, обновление происходит путем полной замены файлов.

Comment: Да, добрый человек, я сейчас посмотрю, напишу потом, может решится проблема этим способом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно причина в том, что вы используете библиотеки с беты, либо обновились до релиза частично.

Дело в том, что `popper.js` не входит в сам `bootstrap`, но входит в `bootstrap.bundle`.

Сообственно, вариантов решения 2:

1. Явно разрешить зависимость и подгрузить [popper.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/popper.js)
2. Использовать [bootstrap.bundle.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js)

Comment: Залил на хостинг релизный файл bootstrap.min.js - и всё заработало

Comment: @Nice Отличненько! Я сам сидел на бете, но ведь это не дело, когда есть релиз =)

Comment: Несомненно нужно быть на острие прогресса)